# What's wrong with my express.router().get method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to [follow this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4), in which the author provides a sample code:

```
// server.js

// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port

// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

// more routes for our API will happen here

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

And I tweaked it a little bit and here is my code:

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ message: 'Hello World!' });
});

app.use('/api', router);


app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

The server runs perfectly but when I visit `localhost:8081`, I get the following message on my browser: `Cannot GET /`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `localhost:8081/api/`

Comment: Thanks! It works now, i forgot about the middleware

Comment: You probably also need to change `function(req, res, next)` to `function(req, res)` in your `router.get()`.  It can behave differently when you pass it three arguments.

Comment: @jfriend00 if he wants to use multiple middlewares on that GET route, then he'd need to use the `next` parameter, otherwise, it can be omitted.

Comment: @roadtocode: Have you set `env PORT` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you added `app.use('/api', router);`

And your route is `router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { res.json({ message: 'Hello World!' }); });`

Then to access `'/'` you need to request with `/api/`

**Update**: If you have set the port on in env use that port or else you should be able to access using [localhost:8081/api/](http://localhost:8081/api/)

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

The above comment is correct.

You have added prefix '/api' to your local server and all incoming request will be `http://localhost:<port>/api/<path>`

```
app.use('/api', router);
```

If you want to access like this (without prefix) `http://localhost:<port>/<path>`
Please update your code to

```
app.use(router);
```